# ReportViewer doesn't display report containing Map

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

The title says it all, really.

I created a Report with a Map in it.
This displays fine in VS, and from the Report Server.

However, when attempting to render it in the ReportViewer aspx control,
nothing gets displayed at all - no error message, just a blank pane.

Using SRSS 2015 and a variety of browsers.

Anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: What are your codes and error messages?

Comment: Which version of SSRS and which browser are you using?

Comment: Info added to OP.